# What function $f(x)$ satisfies $f(\sin(x)-2x)=\ln(x+1)$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I want to know about example of $f(\text{Transcendental function})=\ln(x+1)$ but I think the transcendental function $g(x)$ could have Range of all real numbers.

So I set $g(x)=\sin(x)-2x$, 
$g'(x)=\cos(x)-2 < 0$,
and now I want to know Is there any function $f(x)$ that satisfies the relation below:

$f(g(x))=\ln(x+1)$

Comment: Plugging in $x=g^{-1}$ gives a valid solution, since $g$ is bijective. However, I don't think it'll be expressible in terms of elementary functions...

Comment: @CulDeVu I want to question about that.inverse function about g(x) is what? And will it expressed by elementary funtions?. Yeh.... that's why I posted this.

Comment: Yes, there is a function f such that f(sin(x)-2x) = ln(x+1) for all x > -1. Just define, for all x > -1, f(x) = ln(y+1) where y is the unique number such that sin(y) - 2y = x

Comment: @LeonardBlackburn thanks. I think about it,and I only got there is bijection between......

Comment: Oh, actually you would need to verify that y > -1 (in my comment above) when x > -1, and I don't think that is generally true. So, perhaps there is no such function f.